# Beaglebone: prussdrv_pru_send_event

Tags: beagleboneblack

With a **Beaglebone black**, using the **PRU**, I have to send an event to the binary code, which is just looping.
The binary (assembly) must understand the event and stop the execution sending an event back to PRU_example.c.

PRU_example.c
...

```
/* Load and execute binary on PRU */
prussdrv_exec_program (PRU_NUM, "./PRU_example.bin");
sleep(1);
?? prussdrv_pru_send_event ( ?? ); //kill PRU_example.bin
```

PRU_example.p

```
...
LOOP:
jmp LOOP  // Jump to the lable LOOP
...
HALT
```

I suppose to use the function **prussdrv_pru_send_event**, but how is the code in the assembly?

Answer (score 2):

c++

```
    #include "prussdrv.h"
    #include <pruss_intc_mapping.h>    

    prussdrv_exec_program (PRU_NUM, "./PRU_example.bin");
    sleep(1);
    prussdrv_pru_send_event(ARM_PRU0_INTERRUPT);
    //wait till it will be completed
    prussdrv_pru_wait_event (PRU_EVTOUT_0);
    prussdrv_pru_clear_event (PRU_EVTOUT_0,  PRU0_ARM_INTERRUPT  );
    /* Disable PRU and close memory mapping*/
    prussdrv_pru_disable(PRU_NUM);
    prussdrv_exit ();
```

.p

```
#define PRU0_R31_VEC_VALID 32    // allows notification of program completion
#define PRU_EVTOUT_0    3        // the event number is sent back

.macro  MOV32
.mparam dst, src
    MOV     dst.w0, src & 0xFFFF
    MOV     dst.w2, src >> 16
.endm

#define temp32reg r10    // temporary register 4bytes

// clear interrupt
MOV32     temp32reg, (0x00000000 | 21)
SBCO      temp32reg, CONST_PRUSSINTC, SICR_OFFSET, 4

LOOP:
...
QBBS    END, r31,30      // Exit when receive an interrupt
JMP LOOP

END:
MOV     R31.b0, PRU0_R31_VEC_VALID | PRU_EVTOUT_0 // Send and output interrupt
HALT
```

Comment: What exactly are CONST_PRUSSINTC and SICR_OFFSET here?